# Where should I look for a reliable chainguide for a large chainring (52T)?

Tags: chain, chainring, cyclocross, hybrid-bike

I'm building a hybrid bicycle using a Specialized StumpJumper S-Works carbon frameset.

- The drive-train is 1x12.
- Wolf Tooth 52T cyclocross chainring, to beef up the top end gearing.
  (The chainring is compatible with SRAM Eagle 1x12 drive-train components.)
- 10t-50t rear cassette, for ultra wide range.

I've found a lightweight aluminum bashring that fits 52T chainrings, so that's not an issue.

However, I need to find a **reliable 52T 1x chainguide for 12-speed chains**.

I'm not a huge fan of the chain guides that hang on the frame, and the StumpJumper has odd shapes in the frame bars, making this effectively impossible.

I remember, around a year ago, I found a rare and obscure 52/54T chainguide that mounted on the crankset/BB, but I don't remember anything else about it.

Where should I look for a top/bottom 1x chainguide, crankset/BB mounted, fitting 12-speed chains?

Comment: Why not just go narrow wide and no guide?

Comment: @Paparazzi The chainring I've chosen is already narrow-wide. http://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/collections/cyclocross-road/products/130-bcd-cyclocross-chainrings Do you believe this eliminates the need for a chain guide on a hybrid full-suspension setup? This bike's range is pretty wide, so I will still be climbing hills and traversing hairy terrain, in addition to going very fast when the opportunity is present.

Comment: Does the stock 1X StumpJumper S-Works come with a guide?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes it does, although only on the top of the chainring. https://www.specialized.com/us/en/men/bikes/mountain/trail/sworks-stumpjumper-fsr-650b-frame/115365

Comment: I like absolute black's stuff, they have several minimalist guides that are pretty nice. You might also try running it without one first and find if you have an issue with dropped chains. A lot of narrow wide rings say they work without now a days, some even have a 1 year guarantee. That's what i would do, try it first and then if you have issues look for a guide.